# Save colors for google Pie chart , even slice is 0%

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

> I created a PieChart for the Store on Google Sheets and sometimes I
>   need to copy this file for a new Store. When I do the copy, I take the data from the Google spreadsheet. When I make a copy with TODO-list I lose the
>   colors of diagram and Google sheet takes the default colors for the new slice.

*I wrote some snippets of my code:*

```
     function chartColors() {     
         var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
         var range = sheet.getRange("D2:H16");
         var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
         chart = chart.modify()
             .setOption('colors', ['#808080','#57bb8a','#ffd966', '#afffff', '#b7b7b7', '#ea9999', '#a4c2f4'])
             .build();

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['To Check'],
          ['DONE'],
          ['Already Done'],
          [To Do]  
        ]);

         sheet.updateChart(chart); 
        };
```

**It necessary add name of slice according to the list:**
ffd966 - To Check
57bb8a - DONE
57bb8a - Already Done
808080 - To Do

Can I use data section or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Hi! Your script is working for me, i.e it is coloring the pie chart as your want. What is your actual issue, that when copying the ranges to another sheet or copying the sheet into another spreadsheet you are loosing your defined set of colors for the chart? A sample spreadsheet could help me understand better your question and your issue :D

Comment: Yes, you are right) I'm loosing some defined set of colors. There reason is just because I build the chart which based on data from Importrange columns. When I'm coping new data usualy Importrange function gives only similar data of status "TO DO", because nothing was "Done" yet.